# Uncaught Reference Error: draw is not defined - pls help me

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15Yq3gNNMrk) on making a Ping Pong game using JavaScript and HTML.

I've followed each step in the video multiple times. While my code seems to match the code in video I keep encountering an error: Uncaught Reference Error: draw is not defined. The error occurs in line 20.

I must be overlooking something. Can anyone point it out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pong</title>
</head>
<canvas id="ca" width="720" height="480"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = ca.getContext("2");
    let p1 = p2 = 80;
    let key = {};
    let ball = {};
start();
setInterval(loop, 1000/60)
    document.addEventListener("kedown", e => key[e.keyCode] = true);
    document.addEventListener("kedown", e => key[e.keyCode] = false);
draw();

function start(){
    ball = {
        x: ca.width / 2,
        y: ca.height / 2,
        speedX: 3,
        speedY: 0
    };

}
function loop(){
    if(key[38]){
        p2 -= 5;
    }

    if(key[40]){
        p2 += 5;
    }

    if(key[87]){
        p2 -= 5;
    }

    if(key[83]){
        p2 += 5;
    }

    ball.x += ball.speedX;
    ball.y += ball.speedY;

 if(ball.x < 20 || ball.x > (ca.width - 30)) {
    if(ball.y > p1 && ball.y < p1 + 80 && ball.speedX < 0) {
    ball.speedX = -ball.speedX;
    ball.speedY = (ball.y - p1 -40) * 0.1;
    } 

    if(ball.y > p2 && ball.y < p2 + 80 && ball.speedX > 0) {
    ball.speedX = -ball.speedX;
    ball.speedY = (ball.y - p2 -40) * 0.1;
    } 
}

 if(ball.y < 0 || ball.y > (ca.height - 10)) {
    ball.speedY = -ball.speedY
}

 if(ball.x < 0 || ball.x > (ca.height - 10)) {
        setTimeout(start, 2000);

}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,ca.width, ca.height);  
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
   requestAnimationFrame(drwa);
ctx.fillRect(10, p1, 10,80);

ctx.fillRect(ca- 20, p2, 10,80);

   ctx.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, 10, 10);
}

}
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the only reason is that you can't type XD

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pong</title>
</head>
<canvas id="ca" width="720" height="480"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = ca.getContext("2d"); 
    let p1 = p2 = 80;
    let key = {};
    let ball = {};
    start();
    setInterval(loop, 1000/60);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", e => key[e.keyCode] = true);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", e => key[e.keyCode] = false);
    draw();

    function start(){
        ball = {
            x: ca.width / 20,
            y: ca.height / 2,
            speedX: 3,
            speedY: 0
        };
    }

    function loop(){
        if(key[38]){
            p2 -= 5;
        }

        if(key[40]){
            p2 += 5;
        }

        if(key[87]){
            p1 -= 5;
        }

        if(key[83]){
            p1 += 5;
        }
    

        ball.x += ball.speedX;
        ball.y += ball.speedY;

        if(ball.x < 20 || ball.x > (ca.width - 30)) {
            if(ball.y > p1 && ball.y < p1 + 80 && ball.speedX < 0) {
            ball.speedX = -ball.speedX;
            ball.speedY = (ball.y - p1 -40) * 0.1;
            } 

            if(ball.y > p2 && ball.y < p2 + 80 && ball.speedX > 0) {
            ball.speedX = -ball.speedX;
            ball.speedY = (ball.y - p2 -40) * 0.1;
            } 
        }

        if(ball.y < 0 || ball.y > (ca.height - 10)) {
            ball.speedY = -ball.speedY
        }

        if(ball.x < 0 || ball.x > (ca.width - 10)) {
            setTimeout(start, 2000);
        }
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,ca.width, ca.height);  
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        ctx.fillRect(10, p1, 10,80);

        ctx.fillRect(ca.width - 20, p2, 10,80);

        ctx.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, 10, 10);
    }
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Errors present:**

Line 12: 2 -> 2d

Line 18: kedown -> keydown

Line 19: kedown -> keyup

Line 31: loop function closes at the end of the file (this is the reason why you get Uncaught Reference Error: draw is not defined)

Line 41 and 44: p2 -> p1

Line 67: ca.height -> ca.width

Line 76: drwa -> draw

Line 79: ca -> ca.width

Comment: Discounting the insult at the top, this reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change, why should it solve the problem?

Comment: I was not trying to be rude, it's not my goal, this was just a funny joke, no need to point it out, everybody is a noob at some point, even me and you, actually i'm probably still a noob on lots of things lol

Comment: Hi Guys,
not surprised i can't speak english and therefore write about the google translator.

you've helped me a lot and that's what it counts on.
i am still at the beginning of my programming experience and will also be doing a training course from september.

thanks again for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `draw` function inside the `loop` function so it isn't accessible outside the `loop` function.

If you'd used a tool like this [Online JavaScript Beautifier](https://beautifier.io/) or [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) (which can integrate with IDEs like VS Code) to automatically fix the indentation in your code, this would have been more obvious.